# string concatenation in openquery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, string-concatenation

I Linked Oracle Server to my SQLServer.while framing the concatenation query i am facing problem.Please check below code.

```
select * from openquery(OracleConnection,'select CONCAT(CUST_ADD1,'','',CUST_ADD2,'','',CUST_ADD3) from TDSPARTY where CUST_NAME=''DR GEORGE ABRAHAM''')
```

Error Msg:

> Msg 7357, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Cannot process the object "select
>   CONCAT(CUST_ADD1,'','',CUST_ADD2,'','',CUST_ADD3) from TDSPARTY where
>   CUST_NAME='DR GEORGE ABRAHAM'". The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for
>   linked server "OracleConnection" indicates that either the object has
>   no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that
>   object.

Output required:`CUST_ADD1,CUST_ADD2,CUST_ADD3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle's version of the `CONCAT()` function allows for only two arguments. So you can either use nested `CONCAT()`s:

```
CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CUST_ADD1,'',''),CUST_ADD2),'',''),CUST_ADD3)
```

or you can use the concatenation operator `||` (which is actually defined in the ANSI SQL standard, although SQL Server does not adhere to this standard):

```
CUST_ADD1||'',''||CUST_ADD2||'',''||CUST_ADD3
```

I assume the extra single-quotes `'` are because you're escaping them.

Comment: I don't think OP is trying to escape the single quotation marks. He is just struggling to concatenate the three column values

Comment: He's escaping them b/c the query itself is passed as a string to the `openquery()` function.

Comment: And why have you included double-quotation marks? All you need is concatenate the column values along with a comma in between them.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I included the double quotes so he can just take what I wrote an put it into his function.

Comment: No. You cannot escape a singke quote with just one single quote. You must enclose it with single quotes.

Comment: You are wrong about that, see the `openquery()` documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx

Comment: Double quotes around the comma has nothing to do with escaping single quotes. I hope I am following what you are trying to explain.

Comment: I have no knowledge about an openquery, sorry. All I am saying is that those double quotes have nothing to do with escaping single quotes.

Comment: @LalitKumarB, they are not double quotes (`"`), they are repeated single quotes (`''`). Single quotes need to be escaped when sending queries via `openquery()` which is why I escaped them - so the OP can just copy what I wrote and paste it.

Comment: Alright, perhaps openquery needs that. I was stubborn with Oracle regarding escaping single quotes.

Comment: @Lalit, thanks. Yes, agreed that it is not an Oracle requirement at all in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `concatenation operator` ||

something like -

`select CUST_ADD1||','||CUST_ADD2||','||CUST_ADD3 from...`

**More Information** :

The **CONCAT** function allows you to concatenate two strings together. For more than two strings, you could use **MULTIPLE** concat nested together. However, to keep it simple, you could go with the concatenation operator as shown above.